# refarr text margin too much to the right

Tags: margins

How do I make the text align to the left instead of nearly to the center in refart?
[image]

I want the text to start aligned to the left instead of in the middle

Comment: Can you provide a foundation that replicates the current output? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` that allows the community to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: never mind, I figured it out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `\settextfration<{number between 0 to 1>}` to your preamble.